# Single query alternative to Dynamic PIVOT

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2017

This has been a bit of a brain-teaser for me for a couple of days and I can't seem to solve it.

Basically I have a Project, Resource and Allocation table where I store on a daily basis the Project-Resource allocation. You can use the below queries to build the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Projects ([ProjectID] INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [Name] VARCHAR(100));
CREATE TABLE Resources ([ResourceID] INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,[Name] VARCHAR(100));

CREATE TABLE Allocation (
    [Resource] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Resources (ResourceID),
    [Project] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Projects (ProjectID),
    [Date] DATE);
```

Also, you can use the next queries to generate dummy data:

```
DECLARE @seed INT = 65;

;WITH proj_cte
AS (
    SELECT @seed [seed]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT [seed] + 1
    FROM proj_cte
    WHERE [seed] < 90
    )
INSERT INTO Projects (name)
SELECT 'Project ' + CHAR([seed])
FROM proj_cte;

;WITH res_cte
AS (
    SELECT @seed [seed]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT [seed] + 1
    FROM res_cte
    WHERE [seed] < 90
    )
INSERT INTO Resources (name)
SELECT 'Resource ' + CHAR([seed])
FROM res_cte;
```

And to populate the Allocation table with random dummy data:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ncu_resource_project_date ON Allocation (Resource, Project, DATE);

INSERT INTO Allocation (Resource, Project, DATE)
SELECT DISTINCT ResourceId, ProjectID, AllocationDate
FROM (
    SELECT ProjectID, abs(checksum(newid())) % 26 [ResourceId], cast(getdate() + (abs(checksum(newid())) % 26) AS DATE) [AllocationDate], abs(checksum(newid())) % 26 [filter]
    FROM Projects
    ) f
WHERE f.ResourceId > 0
    AND f.ProjectID > 0;
GO

INSERT INTO Allocation (Resource, Project, DATE)
SELECT DISTINCT ResourceId, ProjectID, AllocationDate
FROM (
    SELECT ProjectID, abs(checksum(newid())) % 26 [ResourceId], cast(getdate() + (abs(checksum(newid())) % 26) AS DATE) [AllocationDate], abs(checksum(newid())) % 26 [filter]
    FROM Projects
    ) f
INNER JOIN Allocation u
    ON u.Resource = f.ResourceId
        AND u.Project = f.ProjectID
        AND f.AllocationDate <> u.[Date]
        AND f.ResourceId > 0
        AND f.ProjectID > 0
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Allocation uin
        WHERE uin.resource = u.resource
            AND uin.project = uin.project
            AND uin.DATE = f.AllocationDate;
        ) GO 250
```

Now, the goal of all this is to write a **single query** (that includes CTE's) that can be parameterized, and that returns a result similar to a cross-section of the Allocation table, based on 2 dates, a `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` (which are the parameters).

The goal output should look something like this:

[image]

I've tried to extend a CTE which generates the date range between `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` and almost got to a working solution with the below query, but it has a few hurdles:

- I still have to manually enter the date ranges in the PIVOT
- I couldn't find an aggregate function for PIVOT that fits my logic (currently I have a "bug" because I use `MIN(Project)` which returns the `MIN(Project)` for that Resource for the entire date range).

  ```
  DECLARE @srcdt DATE = '20180101', @enddt DATE = '20180116';

  ;WITH dates
  AS (
      SELECT @srcdt srcdt

      UNION ALL

  SELECT dateadd(day, 1, srcdt)
  FROM dates
  WHERE srcdt < @enddt
  )
  SELECT pvt.*
  FROM (
      SELECT r.Name AS Resource, p.Name AS Project, DATE
      FROM Allocation u
      INNER JOIN Projects p
          ON u.Project = p.ProjectID
      RIGHT JOIN Resources r
          ON u.resource = r.ResourceID
      ) pvt_src
  PIVOT (min(Project) FOR [Date] IN ([2018-05-01], [2018-05-02], [2018-05-03], [2018-05-04], [2018-05-05], [2018-05-06], [2018-05-07], [2018-05-08], [2018-05-09], [2018-05-10], [2018-05-11], [2018-05-12], [2018-05-13], [2018-05-14], [2018-05-15], [2018-05-16], [2018-05-17], [2018-05-18], [2018-05-19], [2018-05-20], [2018-05-21], [2018-05-22], [2018-05-23], [2018-05-24], [2018-05-25], [2018-05-26], [2018-05-27], [2018-05-28], [2018-05-29], [2018-05-30])) pvt
  ```

I can get this working with a dynamic PIVOT and with Dynamic SQL to generate the date range columns that I `PIVOT` to, but that's already more than 1 query.

Answer (score 1):

It's just not possible to produce a result set of an unknown (or data-driven) number of columns without using dynamic sql.   This isn't a brain-teaser, it's a brick wall.

Comment: It did feel like it to me too. But I thought to ask just in case other people might enjoy the brain teaser or knew more T-SQL.